# Define multiple private functions with same return type and parameters type in one line

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm totally new to `C++` and I was wondering if there's a way to define n functions which have same return type and parameters type in a single line in order to maintain a DRY code.

I tried looking for a solution online and on SO but I wasn't able to find a proper answer.

**myHeader.h**

```
class MyClass{

public:
    . . .

private:
    . . .
    std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*> addVertices(std::vector <Dcel::Vertex*>);
    std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*> randomPointsGetter(std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*>);
};
```

For instance, they both return `std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*>` type and take `std::vector <Dcel::Vertex*>` as parameters input.

**Is it possible to define both of them, or n functions, in the same line? If yes, How?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it is not possible. Edit: You could cheat with a macro I suppose.

Comment: It's possible to use a type alias that names a function type: `using F = std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*>(std::vector <Dcel::Vertex*>); F addVertices, randomPointsGetter;`, but don't use it.

Comment: From the names, there is no inherent connection between these functions, so the fact that they have the same interface isn't a fundamental property that should be documented and maintained; it's simply a coincidence. "DRY" is an oversimplification; don't repeat yourself except when you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the number of functions grows, a macro seems appropriate:

```
class MyClass {

#define MY_PREFIX_DECL_FN(name) \
    std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*> name(std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*>)

    MY_PREFIX_DECL_FN(addVertices);
    MY_PREFIX_DECL_FN(randomPointsGetter);
    MY_PREFIX_DECL_FN(...);

#undef MY_PREFIX_DECL_FN

};
```

Comment: Combining `definition` and `typedef` would be the best choice right? I mean, for a whole definition like `MY_PREFIX_DECL_FN(addVertices);` `define` is perfect but for cases like `void buildTetrahedron(VertexPointersList);` using `typedef td::vector<Dcel::Vertex*> VertexPointersList;` is very good also. Right?

Comment: @AndreaM16 indeed. You can very well use the typedef inside the macro if you so wish.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to define both of them, or n functions, in the same line? If yes, How?

All whitespace is treated equally in C++, so sure. Here are two functions declared in the same line:

```
T function(); T another_function();
```

If you meant whether you could declare multiple functions in one full-expression, or "share" the return type, then no, that is not possible.

---

If you dislike the complexity of repeated `std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*>`, you can use an alias:

```
using R = std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*>;
R addVertices(R);
R randomPointsGetter(R);
```

Edit: This `using` declaration is semantically equivalent with `typedef` as shown in Josh Kelley's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Basically, using `using` or `typedef` is pretty much the same?

Comment: @AndreaM16 they are exactly the same. `using` syntax is available since C++11, so use `typedef` if your compiler is old. I prefer `using` since it's easier to remember which is the type and which is the alias.

Comment: Thank you @user2079303 .

Answer (score 3):

Using a typedef helps cut down on duplication, although it still doesn't let you define multiple functions on the same line.

```
typedef std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*> VertexList;

VertexList addVertices(VertexList);
VertexList randomPointsGetter(VertexList);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can define `N` functions either using `std::vector` or `std::array`:

```
std::vector< std::function(std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*>(std::vector <Dcel::Vertex*>)) > my_private_functions;
std::array< std::function(std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*>(std::vector <Dcel::Vertex*>)),N > my_private_functions;
```

Comment: But those declared functions would not be members of the class.

Comment: You can always use an alias name, like ` auto const& addVertices = my_private_function[0]; auto const&  randomPointsGetter = my_private_function[1];`. And it looks like you are using a method of an instance of this class.